# Circuitikz: a variable esource

Tags: circuitikz

I have to make a component like this
[image]

Is there some elegant way to add this arrow line, like

```
R
```

and

```
vR
```

for resistors? Or, how to add this arrow peak to a line?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to your preamble. They define `xmeter`, which looks like `ammeter`, `ohmmeter` etc but without the letter.

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/xmeter/height/.initial=.60}
\ctikzset{bipoles/xmeter/width/.initial=.60}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole
  {}%
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/xmeter/height}}%
  {xmeter}%
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/xmeter/height}}%
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/xmeter/width}}%
  {\drawmeteringcircle}
\makeatletter
\compattikzset
  {xmeter/.style =
    {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path={\pgf@circ@bipole@path{xmeter}{#1}}}
  }
\makeatother
```

The following picture is obtained by the code below it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
% General measuring device
\ctikzset{bipoles/xmeter/height/.initial=.60}
\ctikzset{bipoles/xmeter/width/.initial=.60}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole
  {}%
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/xmeter/height}}%
  {xmeter}%
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/xmeter/height}}%
  {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/xmeter/width}}%
  {\drawmeteringcircle}
\makeatletter
\compattikzset
  {xmeter/.style =
    {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path={\pgf@circ@bipole@path{xmeter}{#1}}}
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) [short, o-] to [xmeter] (2,0) to [short, -o] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```